# Which code part in bitcoin-core project generates new bitcoin addresses?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, address-generation

i am trying to find out which `c++` code in https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin

is responsible for generating `bitcoin address` and `private key`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `CWallet::GenerateNewKey` in `src/wallet.cpp`.  It calls either `DeriveNewChildKey` or `MakeNewKey` depending on whether HD wallets are in use.